# div and pageblocktable inside a pageblocksection

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to do something I think is pretty simple. I have a pageblock, then a pageblocksection because I want to be able to collapse a table of data.  I've wrapped a div around a pageblocktable in the the section but visualforce is rendering it strange.  It renders the applicationsTable div as one row in the pageblocksection and then the table in another row.  Leaving a giant blank space above the table.  I'm trying to render the div as a way to limit the number of rows the table displays on the screen with a scrollbar to see the rest.  It works fine if I remove the pageblocksection.  I can't use a pageblocksection item because there are too many child components.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Selected Applications" id="applications">
  <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
     <apex:commandButton action="{!ext.refresh}" value="Refresh" reRender="applications" immediate="true"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="true" columns="1" showHeader="true">
    <div class="applicationTableDiv">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ext.applications}" var="app">
        <apex:column>
          <apex:outputLink value="{!app.id}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
      <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.My_Custom__c.FieldSets.DisplayFields}" var="f">
        <apex:column headerValue="{!f.Label}">
          <div class="{!f.FieldPath}">
             <apex:outputField value="{!app[f]}"/> 
          </div>
        </apex:column>
      </apex:repeat>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </div>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave out the `div` and instead add a marker class to your `apex:pageBlockTable` using `styleClass="applicationTable"`. The `apex:pageBlockSection` will have added a parent `div` with the class name `pbSubsection` as part of its normal rendering. (Yes this solution relies on the HTML generated which is not ideal but sometimes hard to avoid.)

Now if [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) supported parent selectors it would be possible to apply your CSS just using CSS. But as they don't, a small bit of e.g. jQuery is needed to go up the parent hierarchy and add the CSS class to the `div`:

```
$('table.applicationTable').closest('div.pbSubsection').addClass('applicationTableDiv');
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  I'm hoping the find a solution that doesn't rely on apex html generation but for now it's doing what I need it to.